# JSON Concatenation

Tags: javascript, json, concatenation

How do I transform this JSON object:

```
"context":{"#text":["Most Visited Pages  "," 
Hall Residents Advanced Components"," Clerk"],"highlight":["City","City"]}
```

into:

```
Most Visited Pages <highlight>City</highlight> 
Hall Residents Advanced Components <highlight>City</highlight> Clerk
```

by using Javascript?

I have tried:

```
 function highlightContext_22(context) {
      var highlighted;
      $.each(context['#text'], function(key, val) { 
           highlighted += val + val.highlight;
      });
      return highlighted;
 }
```

Output is:

```
undefinedMost Visited Pages undefined 
Hall Residents Advanced Components undefined Clerkundefined
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Merlin means "don't post code in comments, edit your question"

Comment: @Moushigo So, you've tried that, and what was the problem with it? What output were you getting and why was it wrong?

Comment: @Merlin sorry about that. First time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `val.highlight` does not exist, which is why you're getting undefined.  Your object has an array value for the key of `#text`.  The `highlight` key is a separate property and thus cannot be accessed in the current context.

The solution below corrects the refence to allow the `highlight` value to be referenced.  *I've added additional indicators for illustrative purposes.*

JavaScript:

```
var obj = {
    "context": {
        "#text": [
            "Most Visited Pages  ",
            " Hall Residents Advanced Components",
            " Clerk"
        ],
        "highlight": [
            "City",
            "City"
        ]
    }
};

var result = [];
var data = obj.context;

for(var i=0; i < data['#text'].length; i++){
    result[i] = data['#text'][i] + (data.highlight[i] ? '<highlight>' + data.highlight[i] + '</highlight>' : '');
}

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result.join('');

alert(document.getElementById('result').innerHTML);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv3vH/

**NOTE**: the above data attempts to compare two arrays of equal length.  Since the `#text` array is one larger than the `highlight` array, there is an undefined value which is not displayed due to the boolean logic to check if the value exists.